Setting environment variable from command stored in array
I have a list of commands which I dynamically read in my script, each command is stored in a line. Some lines contain commands like the following
line="env_var=\"xxx\" myexe -flag1 -flag2"
I'm trying to run all lines (including these) from my script.
Then for each line I do
cmd=($line)
"${cmd[@]}"
However this fails with
env_var="xxx": command not found
I suspect the issue is that in my array declaration the part env_var="xxx" is seen as 1 single word, and somehow I need to put syntatic equals and quotes, but I can't seem to do it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
p.s. I tried eval $line and that works but would like to avoid that.

You have to decide what you would like your file format to be and treat it accordingly. If you want to take in shell statements, then you need to eval them. If you want to take in lists of commands and arguments, then you can do that, but know that env_var="xxx" will no longer be treated as an assignment because that's shell syntax and when you treat it as a command name you will instead get env_var="xxx": command not found

Note that env_var=\"xxx\" and then $line, if it would work, it will set env_var to "xxx" including ", not to xxx.

If you could reliably parse line into an array, you wouldn't need arrays in the first place.

It's not clear why you're trying to avoid eval as what you're trying to do is what eval exists to do but you should do eval "$line", i.e. quoted, not eval $line unquoted for all the usual reasons you don't remove quotes unless you need to (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).
See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 for best practices when using eval and see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more information about storing commands in variables and note it says:

In bash, the only ways to generate, manipulate, or store code more
complex than a simple command at runtime involve storing the code's
plain text in a variable, file, stream, or function, and then using
eval or sh to evaluate the stored code

i.e. that using eval is 1 of only 2 ways (the other being to run a shell on it) to do what you're trying to do robustly.
The negative to using eval (or calling a shell to execute the code in your variable) is that it executes what you tell it to and so if you tell it to execute bad code then bad things will happen, but that's the same problem as telling the shell to execute a script, the only difference being that code stored in a variable is often created dynamically, possibly including input from a user or some other source outside of your control, while that's extremely rare for code stored in a script. So as long as the commands in your input file are completely under your control, you treat then with the same rigor as any script you write, and you just want a way to execute them as if you had created a script for each - then eval is your friend.
Using a command with flags (date) as in the OPs sample input and adding a mix of single and double quotes plus a globbing char (*), potential variable expansion ($bar), command expansion ($(date)), and a complex command in a sample input file to really test that only the correct expansions, etc. happen in the script:
$ cat file
TZ=EST date -d 'yesterday'
TZ=UTC date -d 'yesterday'
env_var='$(date)' awk '{print ENVIRON["env_var"] "\t" $0}' <<<"foo  * $bar"
TZ=UTC env_var="$(date)" awk '{print ENVIRON["env_var"] "\t" $0}' <<<'foo  * $bar'


$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -d '' cmds < file

for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    eval "$cmd"
done


$ ./tst.sh
Sat Jun  1 07:56:19 EST 2024
Sat Jun  1 12:56:19 UTC 2024
$(date) foo  *
Sun Jun  2 12:56:19 UTC 2024    foo  * $bar

which, as desired, is exactly the same output (aside from current time of course) as if we just executed the input file:
$ ./file
Sat Jun  1 07:59:59 EST 2024
Sat Jun  1 12:59:59 UTC 2024
$(date) foo  *
Sun Jun  2 12:59:59 UTC 2024    foo  * $bar

If you want to avoid eval for some reason then instead of using eval we could have done it the other way that https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 recommends which is to pass your command to a shell to execute:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -d '' cmds < file

for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    "$SHELL" -c "$cmd"
done

and also got the desired output but it's not obvious why you'd want to do that. There I'm using $SHELL to run the currently executing shell defined by your shebang, e.g. bash, rather than plain sh in case your file of commands uses bash syntax.
The difference between the 2 approaches is that eval 'command' executes in your current shell and so is more efficient but can affect the value of the variables in your current shell while bash -c 'command' executes in a subshell and so it's variable changes are local to that subshell:
$ foo=3
$ echo "$foo"
3

$ eval 'foo=7'
$ echo "$foo"
7

$ bash -c 'foo=23'
$ echo "$foo"
7

You can, of course, manually put the call to eval in a subshell if you like:
$ ( eval 'foo=345' )
$ echo "$foo"
7

If we try the above input file with xargs env as in the currently accepted answer instead of eval or "$SHELL" -c as above:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -d '' cmds < file

for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    xargs env <<<"$cmd"
done

we get:
$ ./tst.sh
date: extra operand ‘date’
Try 'date --help' for more information.

and even if we simplify the input to just this one line with no command substitution:
$ cat file
env_var='this' awk '{print ENVIRON["env_var"] "\t" $0}' <<<"foo  * $bar"

then it still fails:
$ ./tst.sh
awk: fatal: cannot open file `<<<foo  * $bar' for reading: No such file or directory


You can use env to parse environment assignments and xargs to parse quotes.
line="env_var=\"xxx\" myexe -flag1 -flag2"
xargs env <<<"$line"

Read also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 man xargs and man env. Chec your scripts with shellcheck.

If not eval, the command xargs env will execute in near same way.

Something like line="env_var=\"xxx\" bash -c 'echo \$env_var \$@' -- -flag1 -flag2";declare -a cmd="($line)";declare -n tmpvar="${cmd[0]%=*}";tmpvar="${cmd[0]#*=}" "${cmd[@]:1}" seem closer to the request! ( This output: xxx -flag1 -flag2 ;)
